# Trying to understand GCC generated MIPS code

Tags: c, linux, mips

For the complied code at the bottoms Im trying to understand what the label for the array is, where it keeps values of the add/sub,pos/neg basic stuff. Or just even how it handles the calculation. Any wisdom appreciated

I have this C code

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void calc(int arr[], int size, int* sum, int* pos, int* neg);


int main () {

        int size = 10, sum=0, pos=0, neg=0;
        int arr[10] = {12, -1, 8, 0, 6, 85, -74, 23, 99, -30};
        calc(arr, size, &sum, &pos, &neg);
        return 0;


// Calculation procedure

void calc(int arr[], int size, int* sum, int* pos, int* neg);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
        if (arr[i] > 0)
                pos += arr[i];
        if (arr[i] < 0)
                neg += arr[i];
        }
}
```

Which compiled to this

```
.text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function

main:
.LFB0:
    
.cfi_startproc
    
pushq   %rbp
    
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16  
.cfi_offset 6, -16
    
movq    %rsp, %rbp
    
.cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    
subq    $64, %rsp   
movl    $10, -4(%rbp)   
movl    $0, -8(%rbp)    
movl    $0, -12(%rbp)   
movl    $0, -16(%rbp)   
movl    $12, -64(%rbp)  
movl    $-1, -60(%rbp)  
movl    $8, -56(%rbp)   
movl    $0, -52(%rbp)   
movl    $6, -48(%rbp)   
movl    $85, -44(%rbp)  
movl    $-74, -40(%rbp) 
movl    $23, -36(%rbp)  
movl    $99, -32(%rbp)  
movl    $-30, -28(%rbp) 
leaq    -16(%rbp), %rdi 
leaq    -12(%rbp), %rcx 
leaq    -8(%rbp), %rdx  
movl    -4(%rbp), %esi  
leaq    -64(%rbp), %rax 
movq    %rdi, %r8   
movq    %rax, %rdi  
call    calc    
movl    $0, %eax    
leave
    
.cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    
ret
    
.cfi_endproc

.LFE0:  
.size   main, .-main    
.ident  "GCC: (GNU) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-13)"  
.section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a moment to fix your code. There is no need to post all those empty lines. Also, if you have C code, C++ flag is not relevant. Please avoid adding unrelated tags.

Comment: This is not MIPS code, it's x64 code.

Comment: There is no label for the array. The array is a local variable that is on the stack. So instead, there is an offset, which is -64, in bytes relative to the frame pointer, `%rbp`.

Comment: @selbie not for mips.

Comment: Your code is completely broken. You never *define* `calc()`, because you have messed up your braces and re-declared `calc()` *inside* of `main()`, after the `return 0`,  so the `for`-loop is dead code. [fixed code](https://godbolt.org/z/Yf47exdoY), note that an optimizing compiler can remove pretty much all of your code here, because the only observable side effect is the `return 0;` in `main()`.

Answer (score -1):

Mips code:

```
$LC0:
        .word   12
        .word   -1
        .word   8
        .word   0
        .word   6
        .word   85
        .word   -74
        .word   23
        .word   99
        .word   -30
main:
        addiu   $sp,$sp,-96
        lui     $5,%hi($LC0)
        addiu   $4,$sp,32
        li      $6,40                 # 0x28
        addiu   $5,$5,%lo($LC0)
        sw      $31,92($sp)
        sw      $0,80($sp)
        sw      $0,76($sp)
        jal     memcpy
        sw      $0,72($sp)

        addiu   $2,$sp,72
        sw      $2,16($sp)
        addiu   $7,$sp,76
        addiu   $6,$sp,80
        addiu   $4,$sp,32
        jal     calc
        li      $5,10                 # 0xa

        lw      $31,92($sp)
        move    $2,$0
        j       $31
        addiu   $sp,$sp,96
```